# Removing "node" path from "node/add/*" URLs

Tags: 7, uri

How can I remove the "node" part from "node/add" URLs? I have clean URLs on, and I have successfully used Pathauto to remove "node" from other paths.

Comment: You can't _remove_ it. You can add an alias on top, as suggested in the answers, but  node/add will always be at node/add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to `admin/config/search/path/add` then you can easily alias `node/add/type` to whatever you want.  For example, if you're using a node type called contact-form for a contact page, then just add `contact-form` as an alias for `node/add/contact-form`.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the [Path](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/path) module (in core), and add a new alias.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to create a different path from which you can add nodes, you could also do something along the lines of...

```
function mymodule_menu() {

  $items['add/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'mymodule add',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_add',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE, // or set to your specifications of your site
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;

}

function mymodule_add($type) {
  global $user;

  module_load_include('inc','node','node.pages');
  $node = array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => $user->name, 'type' => $type, 'language' => '');

  return drupal_get_form($type .'_node_form', $node);
}
```

...in a module. I say along the lines of  because a) that's a drupal 6 example and I know you said drupal 7, and b) no security is included in the above either. But at least I hope it's showing how easy it is to extend things.  Also, you just have to make sure there are no namespace collisions, because, unless your "mymodule" is named "add," it is being somewhat rude by claiming "add" as its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the aliases you want created automatically with the [Sub-pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module

(Sorry it's a rather late answer, but hopefully a more useful one for some readers.)